# repeating jquery datepicker in datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

i have the jquery date picker working, but it only works on the first box of the datalist. im having problems getting the datepicker to work on all of the textboxes of the datalist.

heres what i have at the top of my asp.net site, just after `<head>`

```
</head>

<body oncontextmenu="return false" onload="PageLoad()">


<form id="form1" runat="server" >



<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm1" runat="server" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script  src="../development-bundle/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script  src="../development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script  src="../development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script  src="../development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../development-bundle/demos/demos.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

   $("#datepicker").datepicker();



});



</script>
```

heres how i call the datepicker inside the datalist

```
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" ><span style="background-color: #">
                            <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" CellPadding="2"  oncancelcommand="DataList2_CancelCommand" 
                                onupdatecommand="DataList2_UpdateCommand" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                                Width="400px" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" 
                                BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" EnableTheming="False">
                                <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" Width="400px" />
                                <EditItemStyle Width="400px" />
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" Width="400px" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" 
                                    Width="400px" />
                                <ItemStyle Width="400px" Wrap="True" />
                                <ItemTemplate>



                                            Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>


                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" 
                                    Width="350px" />
                            </asp:DataList>
                            </span>


                        </asp:Panel>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <span style="background-color: #">
```

there are more attributes inside the datalist, but i have removed them to avoid confusion.

please help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue here is that you use the control ID, that is inside a repeater and is change. To capture all your date input controls you can assign them a class and then apply the date picker on all controls that have this class. So the html code will be:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="mydate" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

and the second issue is that you need to run this code on every UpdatePanel update, so do not use the jQuery runs but the UpdatePanel function for running on update and on start as

```
<script> 
   function pageLoad(){ $(".mydate").datepicker(); }  
</script>
```

Also remove from form this declaration `onload="PageLoad()"`

Comment: i cannot remove the `onload = "PageLoad()` as it stops other functionality on my page. i have tried your solution and it doesnt seem to work :( no calender appears at all.

Comment: @user2910569 Debug your page and find your javascript errors. My answer works for sure, it you that you make some mistakes. Do not remove the `onload=PageLoad()`, but you need to change this name because you have conflicts with the UpdatePanels